# How to filter certain values when reading csv

Tags: python, csv

So I have a text document with about 11 columns and I need to display specific columns (5 and 6) on a chart. I don't know how to only read those columns. Currently, every single column of data shows when I run the code. Here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jager\Desktop\dataf.txt',sep='\t', index_col=0)


df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns have names you can do:

```
col5 = df['column name']
```

to get the information in the that column.

And since you're importing matplotlib I assume you want to plot using that all you need to do is:

```
plt.plot(df['column 5 name'], df['column 6 name'])
```

For a line plot